# Can I write a chrome extension to change the CSS of a page or site as the page loads?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-plugin

In GitHub, I cannot stand how the side menu is located on the right side when you are in a repository. It drives me nuts, so I want to script something that will change the `float:right` property on the side menu to `float:left`.

A buddy of mine suggested I write a chrome extension for this. Before I look into that, I wanted to get feedback on what options I have to accomplish this.

Comment: https://userstyles.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either use Greasemonkey (named Tampermonkey in Chrome) to add user scripts, or if the CSS element has an unique path to identify it, you can use Stylish to overwrite CSS properties.

I recommend the latter. It is easy and will certainly work.

Comment: or write a simple chrome extension with a content script